# Private variable declaration in implementation file

Tags: c++

Consider this header file:

```
#ifndef __FOLDER_H__
#define __FOLDER_H__

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

class Folder
{
    public:
        Folder(char* arg);

    private:
        std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> files;
};

#endif
```

Everybody including `Folder.h` will also include `boost/filesystem.hpp`. However, there are no boost/filesystem types in the public interface of `Folder`. `boost/filesystem.hpp` kind of leaks out of `Folder.h` for the technical reason of declaring a private variable.

I would like to avoid this. Would it be best to declare private variables in the implementation file `Folder.cc`? Is there some syntax to declare a block of private variables in the implementation file?

Comment: How would Folder be useful without boost/filesystem.hpp? Who would include that?

Comment: Don't use identifiers starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter, identifiers with a double underscore, or identifiers starting with an underscore in the global namespace. They're reserved and using them is undefined behavior.

Comment: @nicomp: This is obviously a shortened example. `Folder.h` as presented here isn't useful at all.

Comment: @user1785730 Obviously wasn't obvious to me and my question stands.

Comment: Check out: [Opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) - also commonly referred to as the 'Pimpl idiom'.

Comment: @BessieTheCow: Could you please elaborate? What would you suggest instead?

Comment: @nicomp _How would Folder be useful without boost/filesystem.hpp?_ That's the point of the question.  Use of this header file is internal to the `Folder` class and the OP wants to keep that fact private to said class.

Comment: if you're talking about your header included define, I use things like FOLDER_H_INCLUDED

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers. Certain identifiers are reserved in C++, meaning that the system may use them internally. If you use those identifiers yourself you can get some weird behavior, so don't. Use identifiers that don't begin with underscores and don't contain double underscores.

Comment: @PaulSanders If that's the case then why is OP concerned about other modules including the header?

Comment: nicomp - because this may be compiled separately

Comment: @nicomp Because it forces any such module to (implicitly) `#include boost/filesystem.hpp` and he seeks to avoid that.  As I say, use of `boost::filesystem` is internal to class `Folder`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few idioms to hide the implementation details of a given class. Two of the ones I tend to use are PIMPL and interfaces.

**PIMPL**

PIMPL is a paradigm where you define a private structure with no definition in the header file, and all of your private implementation details are stored in this private structure. You then reference that structure with a pointer to the implementation, traditionally called `pImpl` (hence the name).

With the PIMPL idiom, `Folder.h` becomes this:

```
//this replaces the include guards and is available in almost all modern compilers.
#pragma once

class Folder
{
    public:
        Folder(char* arg);

    private:
        struct FolderImpl* pImpl;
};
```

And in `Folder.cc`, you can define `FolderImpl` as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

struct FolderImpl
{
    std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> files;
}
```

From there, any operations that work with the `files` member reference it by `pImpl->files`.

**Interfaces**

Interfaces are actually something I "stole" from Microsoft COM. The basic idea is you declare an abstract class, one without any member variables, and inherit from this class in a private header file compiled into your library.

In the Interface idiom, `Folder.h` becomes this:

```
class Folder
{
    public:
        virtual bool DoesFileExist(char* file) = 0;
        virtual File* OpenFile(char* file) = 0;
        ...

        static Folder* Create(char* arg);
};
```

`Folder.cc` looks like this:

```
#include "Folder.h"
#include "FolderImpl.h"

Folder* Folder::Create(char* arg)
{
    return new FolderImpl(arg);
}
```

And `FolderImpl.h` is:

```
#include "Folder.h"
#include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

class FolderImpl : public Folder
{
    public:
        FolderImpl(char* arg);

        bool DoesFileExist(char* file) override;
        File* OpenFile(char* file) override;
        ...

    private:
        std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> files;
};
```

Comment: just make sure the base class destructor is virtual when you derive from it.

Answer (score 1):

At the cost of one level of indirection, you could consider doing something like this:

```
#ifndef FOLDER_H
#define FOLDER_H

#include <memory>

struct FolderPrivateVars;

class Folder
{
    public:
        Folder(char* arg);

    private:
        std::unique_ptr <FolderPrivateVars> private_vars;
};

#endif
```

And then in `folder.cc`

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

struct FolderPrivateVars
{
    std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> files;
};

Folder::Folder(char* arg) : private_vars (std::make_unique <FolderPrivateVars> ())
{
    ...
}
```

Note that this approach hides *all* of `Folder`s private variables from prying eyes, which would (for example) mean that modules using it would not need to be recompiled if these change.  It might, however, have implications if you want to inherit from `Folder`.